# Generate unique file names in Laravel

Tags: random, filenames, uuid, laravel-9

In Laravel when using the storage Facade to save file uploads it uses `Str::random(40)` under the hood to auto generate unique filenames. Source https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/161

I have a requirement for a file upload site to ensue uploaded files have unique filenames.

So my question is `Str::random(40)` adequate in terms of collision proof or should I be using `Str::uuid` instead to generate unique filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Str::random(40)` will be a 40 character alpha-numerical string:

```php
Str::random(40);

// '8Z5x6RG4RQmULcqDLkcUtjyL68qvHckGLXAJH9tv'

Str::random(40);

// 'StLruWT1d7t9DXoN0ixvQ6AqRltvJRWar0M9dl7A'

// ...
```

You can see this generates strings using numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and allowing repeating characters.

If you use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739874/how-many-possible-combinations-in-8-character-password) and adjust the math to remove the 33 special characters (since `Str::random()` doesn't use things like `@`, `!`, `#`, etc.), you still end up with 62 unique options:

- 26 uppercase
- 26 lowercase letters
- 10 numbers

At a length of 40, this equates to 62^40, or 4.9e71, which is an astronomically large number, and one that you're not likely to get a duplicate from.

So in short, **yes `Str::random(40)` is more than adequate.**

If you feel anxious still, you can code in a simple check:

```php
public function generateFilename() {
  $filename = Str::random(40);
  if (Storage::disk('example')->exists($filename)) {
    $filename = generateFilename();
  }

  return $filename;
}
```

(Or similar; adjust to fit your needs as required)